# How to reload Data of TableView when Editing ends with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I'm using a TableView to show, edit and write Data to a file...when the editing modes end I write them to the file and afterwards I want to clear the inputFields of the tableCells.

I'm doing this with:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing == NO) {
        //Write to file

        //Clear Data

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

but when i reload the Data the animation isn't shown.

What way can i reload the Data and still get an animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just clear the input fields in the existing cells instead of calling reloadData? Iterate through all of the UITableViewCells in self.visibleCells and clear the input field in each of them in turn - that should leave the animation uninterrupted.

Comment: thanks :) by now i was reloading the cells with reloadCellAtIndexPath...what also didn't animated really smooth but your idea works much better ;)